# Expectation of Bt^4 given BS

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingale

What is the expectation of Bt^4 and Bt^3 given Bs? Given t>s.

I understand that the expectation of Bt given Bs is Bs and that the expectation of Bt^2 given Bs is something like Bs - s + t.

Answer (score 2):

In general for any question like this the trick is to use the independent increments property:

$$B_t^3 = (B_t-B_s + B_s)^3$$
Then from $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3 ab^2 + b^3$ you have

$$E[B_t^3|B_s] =E\left[ (B_t-B_s)^3 +3(B_t-B_s)^2B_s + 3 (B_t-B_s)B_s^2 + B_s^3 | B_s  \right]\\
=E[(B_t-B_s)^3] + 3 B_s E[(B_t-B_s)^2] + 3 B_s^2E[B_t-B_s] + B_s^3\\
=0+3B_s(t-s) + 0 + B_s^3 \\
= B_s^3 + 3(t-s) B_s$$

Ie. using the property that $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $B_s$.

Brownian motion processes centred at zero have odd moments of zero expectation while conditional ones don't in general.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because your answer is better

Comment: Thanks.. Why is [(−)^3] = 0? Expanding(bt-bs)^3 gets you Bt^3 +3Bt^2BS + 3BtBs^2 + Bs^3 no?

Comment: $B_t-B_s$ has a normal $N(0, t-s)$ distribution so all odd moments are equal to zero.